# Mouse Cursor freezes on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: 20.04, freeze, cursor, mouse-pointer

The cpu is under no load, only browser related things are being done on this machine. It's a Dell Latitude 3520 with i5, 16GB ram and 256GB SSD.

The cursor freezes when using touchpad as well as a wired mouse. Please help me fix this issue.

I don't know what kind of error to post. So, if there's a command of which you would like to know the output of, I will gladly run that command and paste the output here.

Comment: If you open too many tabs in a browser, you can run out of RAM. It makes the system swap and it gets slow.

Comment: Yes, I am aware and this is not the case. I also have 12GB swap

Comment: Big swap doesn't help at all. Check CPU load and RAM usage.